# Javadoc Tooltip with Content Assist in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, content-assist

When i started to use Eclipse's Content Assist, Eclipse used to give me Javadoc help of item i focus in a tooltip box next to content assist. However, after a while Javadoc tooltip stopped working. I tried resetting preferences to default but no luck. What should i do?

p.s: Javadoc works when i highlight an element (i.e. a method).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I mingled with various options for 4 hours...even created a new workspace. Finally what worked for me was some preference changes.

Goto Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist, click on **Restore Defaults**.
Restart Eclipse and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking you have the latest version (and possibly reinstalling) xulrunner. That's Mozilla's platform independent GUI library, and as far as I'm aware it's used to display the javadoc, both content assist popups and in the javadoc tab. The likely cause of your problem is bugs/communication difficulties between eclipse and xulrunner.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem here, and then, armed with Gaurav Kumar tip, I managed to solve it.

The problem here was that I had put a lower auto activation delay value.  When I put it back to 200 and restarted Eclipse, the javadocs came back.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist -> Auto Activation -> Auto activation triggers for Javadoc from "@#" to "@".